# Fuzzy Logic - Smoothing of payoff function: Linear vs. Sigmoid

Tags: options, greeks, barrier, digital

For some options such as digital and barriers it is common to use "Fuzzy Logic" to improve estimation of value and greeks. But how / when are different functions used for smoothing the payoff function?

I've seen two common approaches in the form of applying a transformation using a linear and sigmoid function. But when are one used over the other?